# CS GO: main menu → promt: "equip revolver now"

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Hello I have a small but annoying problem. Everytime when I go into the main menu game will prompt me about equipping R8. I want to disable this!
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Equip then unequip it, and it'll go away.